# Can't find xpath selector for items on dropdown menu

Tags: xpath

At this website:
https://tablebuilder.singstat.gov.sg/table/TS/M015751
I want to change the Frequency from Annual(default) to Quarterly.

I know the xpath of the dropdown menu is

```
button_select5=driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//span[@class='sc-pNWdM XJxhY sc-cbeScs fNvcGj icon-caret-down'])[1]").click()
```

But I can't select "Quarterly"

Answer (score 1):

Try this line

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[.='Quarterly']").click()
```

Comment: How did u manage to find the xpath of the dropdown menu? I couldn't see it. Thanks!

Comment: @123456 I did `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[.='Quarterly']").get_attribute('outerHTML')` to see target node